# Look at the following most carefully as every line counts:

Tags: riddle

Be gone in times of death's long passing,

Henry Atwood s****d his neck,

Hath reeds knocked against thee?

If our fathers knew, then winds they blew,

The sixth of candles burned my eyes,

Horrors even among us,

Leigh tries to eat a stone,

The canine or the cat spat,

Pay attention to the ghoul that weeps.

NOT PART OF THE RIDDLE:

**Your number is up, and it's missing. Wary the word second.**
Try to figure it out.

Comment: I'm  kinda confused about the riddle. What are the asterisks for?

Comment: oh no, the astericks are because it was meant to be 'Henry Atwood sliced his neck', but I was trying to keep it PG rated.

Comment: Oh, ok. I was trying to figure out what the word was, but couldn't. I'm pretty sure 'sliced' is PG though.

Comment: it was either slashed or sliced, i can't remember, but still tryin to keep it PG rated.

Comment: Ok; great puzzle!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The missing number is

> five.

Every line

> "counts" in the sense of containing a number. The numbers run from one ("Be gONE ...") to ten ("Pay atTENtion ...") but five is missing; we go from "iF OUR fathers ..." to "The SIXthe of candles ...".

The final line:

> the "number" is literal; all the numbers overlap the second words of their lines; and "figure" is of course a pun.

Comment: I reckon this was too easy.